# SQL Search query Result

Tags: sql, sql-search

SQL select attract but query I want to give the results as follows.

Select * from table where ???? Result

[image]

Comment: Erm what? There is no question here, please edit and write one including all relevant information.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly

Comment: To be honest I think he want to select those names that got 2 char mark in it ... 17, 3Z, GE, 45 ... that only makes sense

Comment: Select * from table where ???? Result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want .... this is how i would do it

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Temp') is not null drop table #Temp
create table #Temp (FirmName nvarchar(50))

insert into #Temp (FirmName) 
values ('Emlak 17'),
   ('Sanane Emlak'),
   ('GE Emlak => Result'),
   ('45 Emlak'),
   ('Emlak 3Z'),
   ('Burak Emlak')

select * from #Temp
    where Len(LEFT(FirmName, charindex(' ',FirmName, 0))) = 2
       or LEN(RIGHT(FirmName,LEN(FirmName)-CHARINDEX(' ',FirmName))) = 2
```

Just copy paste it and give it a go ... let me know if that worked for you and please man, *read the part* **"How to ask a question"**

Comment: OK thank you so much